# word: non-admins can't update documents on webdav server, admins can

Tags: ms-word, webdav

A customer of ours is using a *kind of* sharepoint (not sharepoint) -a document repository- that, for what I saw, uses **webdav**.

There are two terminal servers, one of them is **Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter v6.1 build 7601**, **Office 2016**, and **Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.17609IS**. **They couldn't access anything at all**, they went as far clicking "edit" on the site and then Word they that he's sorry because he couldn't open the document.

**I've fixed that**, I added the site to the Trusted Sites list, and disabled SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0.  **Local admins can open and update documents**. **Non admin users can open the document but not update it**, and by *can't* I mean that Word opens the document in read-only mode and any attempt to switch to read-write will save the document in the local computer.

Now, the other server, **Windows Server 2012 R2 version 6.3 build 9600**, **Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.19867**, **the former fix did the trick for both admins and non-admins**.

Does anyone know where to look?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Some really ancient stuff here! However, this seems more of a microsoft product support question, than a programming question.

Comment: How does it show up in a non-Admin’s Trust Center? If it doesn’t show as a Trusted Site, then that should answer your question and point you to a solution.

Comment: I dont have the admin access right now (just requested it). For what it's worth: I've compared the trust center in the working server against the non-working one, they're the same.